# How to change 3rd nested array to object type in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [Plugin1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title0
                    [description] => Description0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title1
                    [description] => Description1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title2
                    [description] => Description2
                )

        )

    [Plugin2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title0
                    [description] => Description0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title1
                    [description] => Description1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title2
                    [description] => Description2
                )

        )
)
```

My question is:

I want to update all 3rd array to std object type using php that means like below...

```
Array
(
    [Plugin1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Title0
                    [description] => Description0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Title1
                    [description] => Description1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Title2
                    [description] => Description2
                )

        )

    [Plugin2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Title0
                    [description] => Description0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Title1
                    [description] => Description1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Title2
                    [description] => Description2
                )

        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach($arr as $key => $item) {
  $arr[$key] = array_map(function($val) {
    return (object) $val;
  }, $item);
}
```